# primefaces 4.0 jsf 2.2 can't iterate set with p:dataTable, but can with h:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I know that jsf 2.2 added suport for set datamodel, so now we can iterate over LinkedHashSet, HashSet etc., like we could do it with list before.

I know that primefaces 4.0 supports jsf 2.2.

My problem is that I get 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' exception when I use p:dataTable, but not when I use h:dataTable.

I use latest hibernate core 4.3.1 and WildFly 8, among other things.

So, what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That would help maybe if you give us the main part of the stacktrace.

Comment: @LaurentG  Do you mean:    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ...value="#{author.first_name}": The class 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'first_name'.  The author is LinkedHashSet and with h:dataTable, there is no exception... With p:datatable, well...    The page code is  value="#{book.authors}" var="author"    I found the way by using el3 and adding toArray() like this:  book.authors.toArray(),    and then there is no exception with p:dataTable, but still that is not the wanted solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I posted the question on primefaces forum, here is the link http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36539. It seems that primefaces4 doesn't support java.util.Set yet.

Here is my workaround by using EL3:
`<p:dataTable
   id="someTable"
   value="#{someLinkedHashSet.toArray()}"
   ...rest of the code...
</p:dataTable>`

There are other solutions, ofcourse, but I accept this as an answer cause it's most elegant and simple for my needs.